# How generate dynamic DOM element in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, ant-design-pro, react-modal

I am getting a list of elements over the network. The list size might vary at each call. I have to show the list content in my React ant-design based site. How to generate this dynamic component ? What I did is,

```
export const myModal = props => {


const contactArr = [];

for(let i=1;i<=props.contactList;i++){
    const eachRow = `<Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}>
                        <Col>
                            <Text>Test<Text>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>`
    contactArr.push(eachRow);
}

return (
    <Modal
        visible={props.isVisible}
        width={'40%'}
        onCancel={props.handleEditModalCancel}
        footer={[
            <Button key="back" onClick={props.handleContactModalCancel}>
                Cancel
            </Button>,
            <Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={props.contactModalConfirm}>
                {/*<Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={props.inputSubmit}>*/}
                Submit
            </Button>
        ]}
    >
        <div>
            {contactArr.join('')}

        </div>


    </Modal>
);

}
```

However, instead of rendered rows with columns I am getting simple string output such as,

```
<Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row><Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row><Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row><Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row><Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row><Row style={{border : '1px solid red'}}> <Col> <Text>Test<Text> </Col> </Row>
```

How to get such a rendered output. Is my approach right as I know direct DOM manipulation is not good in React ? Do I need to add any key ?

What is the best way to get my desired result ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use map to create React elements using your data array.

A simple example would be like this.

```
// inside your return statement.
return (
  <div>
    {props.contactList.map(contact => { 
      return <p>{contact}</p>
    })
  </div>
)
```

Another example

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3]

  return (
    <div>
     {numbers.map(num => {
       return (
         <div>
            <p>{num}</p>
         </div>
       )
     })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This works. Just a small suggestion, you need to add a "key" to each <div>

Comment: and is there a way that I define my logic in a variable and just place the variable inside curly braces , inside the return statement.